# convert 5v AC to 3.3 DC

Tags: wiring

I'm working on my raspberry pi door bell and facing the electricity problems that is beyond my knowledge, please help

What I have:
one AC wire from door bell, it's around 0V when Idle, then when someone press the door bell button, it increases to 5V AC

What I want to achieve:
My RPi needs the 3.3V DC input to monitor the "Button Press" action, so my first thought was to get a relay or transformer to convert the 5V AC to 3.3V DC.
So I brought one from amazon, something called Adjustable Power Module/Regulator, here's the link: [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0052YHXOA?psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o02_s01](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0052YHXOA)

What's my problem:
well, it doesn't work, the multimeter shows 0 or a very low voltage (around 0.3V) from the DC output from that Module, so I guess that I was getting the wrong thing

I'm asking around to find out any idea or any solutions to convert my 5V AC to 3.3V DC, so I can connect to my RPi to continue the project

tks in advance and Merry Christmas to everyone!

Comment: Do you have access to a soldering station with some protoboard? This problem can be solved pretty easily with 2 resistors and a diode if you do.

Comment: tks for the quick reply Perkins, I'm not too sure about the soldering station with some protoboard, you mean something like a breadboard? sorry the hardware wiring part is just not my expertise, I'd love to learn more if you can provide me a bit more details

Comment: More something like this. Allows you to build your own small circuits by soldering in components and wire to create connections.
 http://blog.mklec.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/mk-vb26.jpg

Comment: A breadboard would also work fine. Breadboards are obviously less permanent than protoboard (if that's actually what it's called) and solder.

Comment: Well I wouldn't use it for any permanent solution, and it sounds like he's after a permanent solution @immibis

Comment: Ok, so the soldering w/ protoboard sounds just a constant version of the breadboard, got that. Now is there any place I can learn or find some solutions to use this technic to build a low AC incoming voltage sensor? tks

Comment: Easiest and ***safest*** solution, get a wireless doorbell, and connect your RPI to the receiver. No AC, not potential safety issues.

Comment: @Passerby it's not possible, i'm living in an apartment and I have no control about the door bell installation, btw, regular wifi signal is out of reach from the apartment main door to 6th floor where I'm living...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think using a full-bridge rectifier is a bit too trusting. I don't like connecting digital pins to mains, even through a transformer. A transient fault could obliterate your RPi.

Here's my approach - use an optoisolator to provide an isolation barrier. The diode inside the optoisolator conveniently doubles as a half-wave rectifier. I paralleled a capacitor with the ballast resistor on the optoisolator output. This forms an envelope detector.

[image]

Here's what the voltage at the output of optoisolator looks like. I had the AC supply on for half a second, then it switched off:

[image]

This would probably be fine to feed into the Pi but I personally didn't care for the ripple, so I added a comparator midway between 3V3 and ground. This is what the 3V3_BELL_DETECT output looks like alongside the input:

[image]

LTSpice sim is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8wevrD3TcWAcU1FSFdzRzdXNWc/view?usp=sharing) if you want it.

Comment: +1 for the optical isolation. This is the best way to ensure safety to pi. Also, I don't think ripples will create a trouble as long as signal is above the LOGIC HIGH threshold. Op might have to experiment a little with R1 and C1 values though. 0.1uF ceramic and 400K seem to work fine in one of the circuits I designed. Opto-coupler was PC817.

Comment: From this description I don't think it's actually connected to mains at all. It outputs 5v. There's no mains rectification needed.

Comment: Considering it's AC it'd be going through a transformer down to 5VAC. That does imply isolation but there's a couple reasons I wouldn't trust that. One, there's a small chance it's not an isolation transformer - it could be an autotransformer (although I admit that's not likely). Two, even it is an isolation transformer there's no guarantee its ground reference is going to be the same as the RPi - it could be referenced to system neutral for all we know. Without ripping apart the wiring to find out I think optoisolation is the safest way to go.

Comment: @NathanielJPerkins Dangerous assumptions are dangerous

Comment: @PeterK one thing of note, you have inadvertently shared ground between the isolated sections of your simulation.

Comment: @Daniel: Yes, good catch. In the actual circuit the two grounds are separate. I don't think LTSpice can simulate independent floating grounds though - I suppose you could do something like add a virtual ground net that's lifted by a certain voltage from the actual ground.

Comment: @PeterK Eh, I would probably just throw a \$1G\Omega\$ resistor in there to provide a reference. Not that it matters for the simulation.

Comment: @Daniel: I think this does the trick: http://i.imgur.com/R4ROMSv.png

Comment: hi @peterK, tks for the diagram, a little bit complicate to me but I'm learning, will try to get the things you mentioned like a optoisolation, let's see how it goes.

Comment: @peterK the diagram seems a bit complicate to me, I will try to spend some time to learn it, is it too much ask to translate into newbie's language? lol. I have a set of resistors, as well as some diodes, need to buy an optoisolator, do I need a protoboard/breadboard or even some soldering part too?

Comment: I'm not sure where you are in the world / where has cheap shipping. I'm in Canada so I usually just do a DigiKey order every so often ($8 overnight shipping). Cheap optoisolator: http://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/LTV-817/160-1366-5-ND/385836. Cheap comparator: http://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/AS393P-E1/AS393P-E1DI-ND/4770656. Note that the comparator is open-collector type so you'll need a pullup on the output to +3.3V.

Comment: As for a good description of how optoisolators work, google is your friend. Here's a decent beginner-friendly description: http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/blog/optocoupler.html.

Comment: @PeterK great, that's something to start with, believe me I did google a lot for this, but it's just too much to dig.. kinda got lost.. :(

Comment: For those who want to help Joe out, let's [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33335/discussion-between-peter-k-and-joe-lu). I think this question has been answered satisfactorily otherwise.

Comment: @PeterK Just found some additional pieces in my RPi package, some capacitors and few Photoresistors, is Photoresistors same as optoisolator? tks

Comment: @PeterK just disregard my previous question, I documented myself on this :) so I'm going to follow your diagram and start working on the breadboard first, maybe some math on om theory too :) tks for everything, please let me if you'd like to add anything on

Comment: got the optocoupler @PeterK referred, didn't read anything from the output, am I doing anything wrong? One thing that I realized is that the optocoupler input requires DC type, should I get a different one other than the one PeterK recommended? http://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/LTV-817/160-1366-5-ND/385836 (this is what i got), tks

Answer (score 0):

Edit: It's now obvious that the OP has no idea if the doorbell transformer is fully isolated, and has no way to tell. In that case, this is a bad approach.

---

Do you have any idea if this circuit is isolated by the doorbell transformer? That would make this very simple.

Something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuazWh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Edit: Added R2 to drain off capacitor when doorbell is released.

Comment: Hi Daniel, tks for the reply.

Comment: I don't have much knowledge about the physical wiring, in my apartment, I have a single black wire from the wall, where it should connects to the main apartment door. The wire has no voltage at all until someone press the door button, then I read it from my multimeter, it shows 5V AC

Comment: Maybe you should just use a 5V relay then...

Comment: Out of curiosity, where do you connect the other lead of the meter? One wire is not sufficient to make a circuit!

Comment: i just connect it to the metal heat pole, and yes, if i don't connect to the metal pole, the multimeter shows 0 whatsoever

Comment: I couldn't find any AC-DC relay supports 5V incoming, usually it only supports 120V AC input, do you have any advices? tks again

Comment: What's a "heat pole"?

Answer (score -2):

For a cheap and easy solution, the following circuit can be used. For further reading, this is a half wave rectifier. Daniel's is a full wave rectifier. For your application though, you don't need a full wave solution, you just need to detect a peak, and this solution will give you that.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhYIFe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The AC source only has it's positive wave rectified into usable DC, so directly after the diode it's experiencing positive DC voltage of up to 5v - diode voltage. The voltage divider of R1 and R2 then step the voltage down to approximately 3v3, so it will trigger the Raspberry pi.

It's a simple enough circuit to prototype on your own breadboard and get working, as well as solder it yourself on a more permanent piece. Note that the capacitor isn't strictly necessary, but helps to smooth out any potentially damaging voltage spikes. Further protection could be added in the form of a zener diode on the RPi_input node.

Comment: this is simple enough to understand, I will go ahead to give a try on the breadboard first, hopefully it will work, tks again

Comment: This isn't safe, and probably won't even work for several reasons! 1) How do you know the AC from the doorbell is at the same potential as the Pi ground? 2) Where is your connection to the Pi ground, how does the circuit get its earth reference? 3) 1 kOhm is much too small to save the Pi. 4) 5 volts AC has a peak value of 7 V, so you're not dividing it down enough.

Comment: @joelu this circuit as currently drawn will almost certainly toast your Pi as soon as you connect it. Please use an opto-isolator or a relay.

Comment: tks tomnexus, I guess I have to seek some other solutions, my Pi is still not cooked :) however, still appreciate Nathaniel's effort, thank you